# PHP, синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
var $createdatabase = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.$this->sql_database;
```

$this->sql_database - переменная наследуемая из дочернего класса.
Ругается на точку.
Если поставить кавычки:

```
var $createdatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $this->sql_database";
```

Начинает ругаться на первую кавычку, что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так никто и не дал правильного ответа:

1. Вы пишете на PHP4? Нет? Так почему жt Вы используете устаревшее ключевое слово var, а не protected, public, private?
2. В объявлениях переменных нельзя использовать конструируемые значения. Для этого обычно используют функцию конструктора.
3. Советую использовать дополнительные функции mysql_real_escape_string и т.п. при добавлении параметров.

P.S. Ставлю Вам двойку за знание PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Ну правильно ругается. Родитель и не должен видеть что-либо в дочернем классе. Чтобы убрать ошибку, надо определить переменную sql_database в родительском классе, но изменение значения в дочернем классе не повлечет изменения значения переменной в родительском классе.

Comment: а зачем мне ее объявлять если она уже объявлена и проинициализирована в дочернем классе?

Comment: А откуда родительский класс о ней должен знать? Это потомки могут знать о наследованных членах и методах (не всегда, впрочем), но не наоборот.

Comment: я перепутал, извините в родительском переменная проинициализированна, а в дочернем я ее пытаюсь использовать. В общем вопрос интересный, ответ я нашел, жалко что меня сразу не поняли. Оказывается нельзя инициализировать переменными другие переменные класса нужно использовать функцию тогда все равботает. Очень плохо что вы не разобрались в вопросе и начали минусовать, поверьте, различить undefined variable, и undefined '"', '.' я могу.

Comment: Вам следовало бы терминологию подучить, тогда, вероятно, формулировки были бы более понятными.
У класса есть поля и методы.
И вообще стоит сразу переходить к разделению методов и данных, имхо.
Поле должно быть private, а вот методы для чтения/записи данных в это поле уже могут быть public или protected. Тогда путаницы такой точно не возникнет в дочернем классе.

Answer (score 2):

Короче говоря, ling прав, объявите переменную в текущем классе, либо обращайтесь к ней соответственно:

```
\ClassName::getSqlDatabase();
```

или:

```
$ClassLink->sql_database;
```

$ClassLink - можно притащить с собой как параметр функции, а можно, например, через global:

```
global $ClassLink;

$ClassLink->...
```

И будет вам счастье :)

UPD:
Совсем забыл про parent :)
Это еще один вариант, но конкретно сказать сложно - нужно видеть структуру :)

```
parent::...
```

Comment: Это ужасная кривизна

Comment: Не я же проектировал проект :) Отвечаю на то, что уже сделано и описано в вопросе - других вариантов я не вижу :)